# c pointer understanding issue

Tags: c, pointers

Please have a look at the following code and tell me where does `***ptr` locates ?
i.e. i have a feelings that `***ptr` actually locates at `ptr[0][0][0]`
Am I wrong ? The following is a 3d representation of pointer. where I am trying to assign some characters and later i wanted to test what is the index of `***ptr`? will be waiting

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define row 5
#define rw 3
#define col 10


char ***ptr;
int i,j,k;


void main()
{

clrscr();

ptr=(char *)malloc(row*sizeof(char *));

for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        *(ptr+row)=(char *)malloc(rw*sizeof(char *));
        printf("\t:\n");

           for(j=0;j<rw;j++)
           {
           *(*(ptr+row)+rw)=(char *)malloc(col*sizeof(char *));
           if(i==0 && j==0)
               {       //   *(*(ptr+row)+rw)="kabul";
            **ptr="zzz";

               }
           else
            *(*(ptr+row)+rw)="abul";
           printf("\taddress=%d %d%d = %s\n",((ptr+row)+rw),i,j,*(*(ptr+row)+rw));

           }

         printf("\n");
    }


printf("%c %d",***ptr,ptr);
getch();
}
```

Comment: you are doing one thing wrong (2 times). assigning memory to location *(ptr+row) writes it to one place (only one even though it's a loop. you need to write it to *(ptr+i) (repeat with all mallocs in loops

Comment: dude i m trying to implement a 3d array here. so m i not supposed to have 2d loop for the 2nd index and the 3rd index and ending up with writing malloc 3 times in the code ?

Comment: Do you try to create a two-dimensional array of string perhaps? From your code I am not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: ptr[0][0]="abul" means ptr[0][0][0]=='a' in that case i have created a 3d array. what i m trying know is what is the equivalent indexing for ***ptr??? as we can assign ***ptr='p' where is that ? There has to be an indexing point for it ... is not it ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I find your coding style extremely hard to read.

Answering your question, yes, `ptr[0][0][0]` is a synonym of `***ptr`. Thats because `a[b]` is by definition equal to `*(a+b)`, so `ptr[0]` is equal to `*ptr`, etc.

Said that, here is my version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#define row 5
#define rw 3
#define col 10


char ***ptr;

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    ptr = (char***)malloc(row * sizeof(char **));

    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        ptr[i]= (char**)malloc(rw * sizeof(char *));
        printf("\t:\n");

        for(j = 0; j < rw; j++)
        {
            ptr[i][j] = (char*)malloc(col * sizeof(char));
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                strcpy(ptr[i][j], "zzz");
            }
            else
            {
                strcpy(ptr[i][j], "abul");
            }
            printf("\taddress=%p %d,%d = %s\n", ptr[i][j], i, j, ptr[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Note the following changes:

- Never write `void main` in C or C++. And throw away any book that prints it.
- The argument of `malloc` is usually the number of elements times the size of the element. Place special attention to the real type that you intend to use.
- The return of `malloc` is usually cast to the type *pointer-to-the-type-of-the-element*.
- The index in the arrays should be `i` and `j`, not `row` and `rw`.
- Why all the `*(ptr + x)` stuff? That's why we have the `ptr[x]` syntax.
- You probably want to use `strcpy` to fill your strings, but difficult to say without explaining the problem.
- When you want to `printf` a pointer, use `%p`.
- If you use `malloc`, include `<stdlib.h>`.
- Prefer local variables (`i`, `j`) to global ones, particularly for loops.
- And a few other minor changes here and there...

PS. `<conio.h>`? Really? Are you still using Turbo-C or what?

Comment: Didn't you know, MS-DOS devs are in high demand right now! ;)

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Nobody is making fun of you, but if you don't want your code to be criticized you shouldn't post it on the Internet.